# xparse verbatim argument removing multiple space

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim, xparse

I am trying to define a command, using `xparse` that take as input some verbatim code and cite it using `listing`. However, the eventual multiple white spaces or tabulations at the beginning of a lines always get removed and it only stays one space left.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{+v}{
    \begin{lstlisting}^^J
        #1^^J
    \end{lstlisting}
}
\begin{document}

\test{
some code
    some code indented
}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: MWE Results]

The first line has no white space before it begins which is correct. But the second one should be indented 4 spaces, not one!

Comment: The problem (as almost always) is that using verbatim-like environments in arguments fails as tokenisation has happened. Here, `xparse` is doing exactly what it's expected to do _but_ `listings` doesn't just want a 'string': it makes spaces active. Thus 'this can't work'!

Comment: @JosephWright What solutions are there then? I cannot find a way to produce verbatim text *and* do some normal macro things before (as typesetting a title for example). Is there any way to define a command *with arguments* that take one of them to produce verbatim text?

Comment: Why don't you use some environment with preprocessing? That could use `lstlisting`. Btw: The listings package documentation gives also some advice on own environments.